# "No certificates were found for decryption" (Apache CXF, WS-Security)

Tags: java, soap, cxf, ws-security

I am building a web service and would like message level encryption.  The encryption must use Asymmetric binding.  I am new to Apache CXF so I used one of their samples and worked on converting it to fit my requirements.  However when I changed the symmetric binding to asymmetric binding, I started getting the following error after the client sends an encrypted message to the server:

"No certificates were found for decryption (KeyId)."

I understand that this is probably a cert error but it may also be configuration related.
I am positive that I have public and private keys for both the client and the server.  Messages are encrypted by the client with the public key of the server and signed with the client's private key.  The server is configured to verify the signature with the client's public key and then decrypt with the server's private key.  However I didn't know what code needed to be changed as I switched from symmetric to asymmetric binding.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Here are my configurations for the encryption and the ws-security policy.

ServiceConfig.xml:

```
<entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value="etc/Server_Decrypt.properties"/>
<entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="etc/Server_SignVerf.properties"/>
<entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value="demo.hw.server.UTPasswordCallback"/>
```

Server_Decrypt.properties:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=******
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=serverx509v1
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=keystore/server-keystore.jks
```

add_numbers.wsdl

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="AddNumbersPolicy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>    
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic128Sha256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss11>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="AddNumbersPartsPolicy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:EncryptedParts>
            <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know the exact cause without seeing the stacktrace...However note that for the Asymmetric Binding, the keys used for decryption actually come from the "ws-security.signature.properties" property ("ws-security.encryption.properties" is used to secure the response to the client). So make sure that the private key required to decrypt the request is in the signature properties keystore.

Colm.

Comment: You are amazing - that did the trick!  I had to reference my Server_Decrypt.properties file in ws-security.signature.properties.  Is this common knowledge or did I overlook some important documentation?